# After installing AMD RX 480 driver on Ubuntu 16.10, cannot get to login

Tags: drivers, graphics, 16.10, amd-graphics

I recently upgraded to an RX 480 and installed Ubuntu 16.10 gnome desktop. Because the default/open source drivers were glitchy, i downloaded the latest drivers from AMD's website, the 16.50 drivers, and after installing and rebooting all i can get to is TTY and Grub. If i do sudo service gdm restart it freezes. How do i fix this?

Comment: Exactly what AMD drivers have you installed. A link would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to boot into the multiuser target with `sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target` and rebooting.
Then go back to your AMD graphics installer binary and run it again, this time passing --uninstall to it.

I have this exact problem and am just using glitchy open source drivers for my graphics card since it is newer. Older graphics card have great support, I just happen to have a niche laptop. Remember to set your boot target back with `sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target`

Comment: This did not help. Now I just get a black screen after boot up until I do Ctrl alt f2

Comment: This was how to uninstall the drivers that were just installed to revert to the old drivers. Do you have the original drivers installed? Here is a link to the official documentation on working with AMD fglrx drivers: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD

Comment: When I tried "suds apt-get install fglrx I got no installation candidate